# Jenkins inside docker loses configuration when container is restarted

Tags: jenkins, docker

I have followed the next guide https://hub.docker.com/r/iliyan/jenkins-ci-php/ to download the docker image with Jenkins.

When I start my container using `docker start CONTAINERNAME` command, I can access to Jenkins from [localhost:8080](http://localhost:8080).

The problem comes up when I change Jenkins configuration and restart Jenkins using `docker stop CONTAINERNAME` and `docker start CONTAINERNAME`, my Jenkins doesn't contain any of my previous configuration changes..

How can I persist the Jenkins configuration?

Answer (score 11):

You need to mount the Jenkins configuration as a volume, the `-v` flag will do just that for you. (you can ignore the `--privileged` flag in my example unless you plan on building docker images inside your jenkins docker image)

```
docker run --privileged --name='jenkins' -d -p 6999:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /home/jan/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home jenkins:latest
```

The `-v` flag will mount your  `/var/jenkins_home` outside your container in `/home/jan/jenkins` maintaining it between rebuilds.

`--name` so that you have a fixed name for the container to start / stop it from.

Then next time you want to run it, simply call

```
docker start jenkins
```

Comment: Ok, I got it. But I didn't do that with my ssh keys and these ones persist when I restart the container. How do you specify in the dockerfile: Ignore this folder? Or... Why is jenkins folder ignored? Why are my keys perisisting? Where is it specified?

Comment: Any changes you make to the container will remain there, until you rebuild it or build a new one, that includes your ssh keys and jenkins config. For it to survive between rebuilds as well, you need to mount those directories outside of your container. If your jenkins config disappears between restarts, I'll need more information on your setup (example if your user has write access to the directory, etc). If it still disappears after mounting it and you can see it in your mounted directory, then something is obviously deleting it on startup.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.1'
services:

  jenkins:
    image: jenkins:latest
    container_name: jenkins
    restart: always
    environment:
      TZ: GMT
    volumes:
      - ./jenkins_host:/var/jenkins_home
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    tty: true
```

You only need to share the jenkins volume ./jenkins_host:/var/jenkins_home with host folder

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the init script

```
/sbin/tini -- /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh
```

is reseting jenkins configuration on startup within the folder provided through the 
JENKINS_HOME env var, 
wether mounted outside the docker vm or not.

It is but possible to store the configuration on github using 
 configure/"Configure System"/"SCM Sync configuration"/Git 
section.

See possible detailed configuration [here](https://antonfisher.com/posts/2017/01/16/run-jenkins-in-docker-container-with-persistent-configuration/)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the obvious, like running parameters that clear up the image that you should disable, you can do a few things:

- use docker commit and reuse the commited container
- mount the part where you write to the local file system with docker volumes
- my favorite : use command :

  docker container restart containername

Depending on your needs you can pick one.
I use the latter for example when testing jenkins plugins and it retains the data inside.
Source of the latter that is also useful for updates:
https://jimkang.medium.com/how-to-start-a-new-jenkins-container-and-update-jenkins-with-docker-cf628aa495e9

Answer (score 0):

Seems like we need to mount 2 folders in `volumes` **if we need to preserve update of jenkins itself**:

1. `/var/jenkins_home` - it stores common jenkins data
2. `/usr/share/jenkins` - it stores updates of jenkins app, the `jenkins.war` file

I just tested that: remove /usr/share/jenkins from volumes and restart container and I see old version of Jenkins.